# Azure AD SSO not redirecting to "Redirect URL" mentioned on the webpage and Azure Portal

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I am trying to establish SSO using Azure AD, but facing a peculiar condition. When I first try to login via application url, it redirects me to AD login page. After successful authentication, a cookie is generated. But the redirection does not take place to the original uri that I opened.
It goes to domain controller page where it says 403- forbidden access.[image]
But, after refreshing the page, site opens normally like how it should have in the 1st time itself.

> Original URL: https://**-webapp*.t**l.co.in/TSEERMDEV/
>
> During login:
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/f35425af-4755-4e0c-xxxx-b3cb9f1c6afd/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=cccccccc-219d-4c3b-bbc9-a1d32caa79a3&post_uri=https%3A%2F%2F**-webapp*.t**l.co.in%2FTSEERMDEV%2F&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DP2o_ddgKlg9kRjVV49yxtFnHEZPT-i4ROq2k7zUVGDv0SzlhfhKy8WLkinKE_IFSgN2tWpJt4Jte-Y34NIod0mmmmmmmmsssssssstetstesteB7IOnFZUKVyv-kNbXQev25viPA-5TDi2sIkhBPSZKwSzvCP9cu_7VRNk5v53Ekjo032xjNA_-R-ulXWAW_SM3O6zqh6otO3O1tR1xpXQ8A&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637594416396999271.ZDA5M2Y4MGYtMmFiNC00OGJhLThhMDUtNDY5YTNlYTU1NTRhNzUwZjdiMDUtZGZmNy00YjMNC44GGMtNmQyYzliNzNkYjA4&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0

redirect url: https://**-webapp*.t**l.co.in/TSEERMDEV/

Answer (score 0):

Your original URL: `https://-webapp*.tl.co.in/TSEERMDEV/` is invalid, and the invalid url cannot be added as the redirect url of the application.

[image]

So, you need to set the correct redirect url, and then you can try to use this url to send a login request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Comment: Hi Carl, url was masked (I have masked it for this post). I can reach url after logging in (2nd time refresh-after successful authentication from Azure).